# Xamarin Forms: How to change the background color of the Master Detail content page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-color, master-detail

I have a master-detail page in my project and added some content pages into it as the children. How I can change the color of the top bar of the child content page?  I have added some icons on the top bar using `<NavigationPage.TitleView>`.

[image]

I need to change the red square background color. Already I tried the solution preferred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623635/xamarin-forms-control-the-color-title-of-the-header-bar), but that not solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change that Navigation bar's background color for **Android** follow the following steps:

```
Go to your Android Project -> Resources -> values -> styles.xml
```

Open style.xaml file update `colorPrimary` value with your required hex color code

```
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3478c9</item>
```

For **iOS** this can be controlled from App.xaml file, no need to write anything in iOS project

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

      <!-- Styles -->
      <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#3478c9"/>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"/>
      </Style>
      <!-- Styles -->

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: For ios how can I change the color?

Comment: I need to change the color for all platforms.

Comment: Updated my answer, try once

Comment: Update you soon

Comment: This change will afftect for all the navigation page children of master-detail page?

Comment: Yes, so as to maintain the uniformity of application's UI

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In order to even get `NavigationPage.TitleView` to work, I had to set `android:theme="@style/MainTheme"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.  I then tried changing all the colors under `styles.xml` and `colors.xml`, but none of them seem to change anything.