# TargetType ShellContent style Maui

Tags: xaml, styles, maui, flyout, targettype

I would like to apply a common style for each `ShellContent` element in my app.xaml.

My problem is that I don't see any `ShellContent` property in my `TargetType`

AppShell.xaml

```
<ShellContent Title="TITLE1"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
              Route="Route1"
              Icon="Icon1" />

<ShellContent Title="TITLE2"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"
              Route="Route2"
              Icon="Icon2" />
```

I would like something in this style in my `App.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="ShellContent">
       <Setter Property="Title" Value="{StaticResource Black}" />
</Style>
```

[image: ShellContent Menu]

Comment: If `Black` is a color, setting property `Title` to it doesn't make any sense; Title sets the string text of a page. Are you looking for property `Shell.TitleColor`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517339/199364

Comment: The value is just an example. I'm just looking to target the title property of ShellContent to change the color as I want, font etc...

Answer (score 0):

In `Styles.xaml`, which is merged into `App.xaml`, find and change the styles applied to `Shell`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="HotPink" />
    <!--TBD_WHAT_PROPERTY?? <Setter Property="Shell.FontFamily" Value="..." /> --/>
</Style>
```

This will change the color of Titles of ShellContents, on tabbar (On Android, but not on Windows - bug?), and on each page.

Unfortunately, I have not found any way to change the properties of the flyout.

Unfortunately, I have not found any way to change the font used.

Comment: Your example is used to focus the title of the page, not the title of the ShellContent element.

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of what I want to change.

The example of the color was not really to be taken into consideration, in my case I would like to change the font etc.. In fact, I just want to have access to all the properties of my ShellContent to be able to change them as I want.

Comment: Edited answer, but it still isn't the ShellContent location you are referring to, which from your image, is on the Flyout.

Comment: Thanks for your precise answers, unfortunately I'm looking to change the titles of the Flyout.

Comment: Might be possible by writing "custom renderers" per platform. I don't know what "native controls" Shell uses on each platform. Seems likely that would be a major effort, with little help from current documentation. I recommend creating a new issue at `github maui issues`.